# Merging tables by row/ rbind tables with different column lengths/names by row

Tags: r, merge

I've many tables containing different ARIMA-Orders from a time series analysis. A short example would be something like this:
The two tables are Order1 and Order2 containing a) different orders b) different frequencies of combinations.

```
Order1
(1,0,1) (1,1,1) (2,1,4)
     4       5       9

Order2
(1,0,1) (3,0,4) (0,1,1) (2,1,2)
    1        2       7       10
```

In the previous step the two tables are sorted by sort(Order1) and sort(Order2)

I want to merge both tables, by row to get one "big" table with two rows.
My expected Output should be something like this:

```
          (1,0,1) (1,1,1)  (2,1,4) (3,0,4) (0,1,1) (2,1,2)
Order 1        4       5        9       0      0        0
Order 2        1       0        0       2      7        10
```

or if its possible just the two input tables in one big table with "different column names and lentghs"

```
        (1,0,1) (1,1,1) (2,1,4)
Order 1      4       5       9 
        (1,0,1) (3,0,4) (0,1,1) (2,1,2)
Order 2        1     2       7      10
```

I tried something like merge or rbind, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do these two tables come from the same dataframe ? How do you create them ?

Comment: No this tables are the results of a self written function, that I ran two times.

Comment: Created with `table` ?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(Order1)` and `dput(Order2)` in your post. This will be clearer like this.

Comment: My example above was just a reduced example. The correct results are: > dput(ARIMA_Order)
structure(c(1L, 3L, 29L, 54L, 58L), .Dim = 5L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("( 2 1 1 ) ( 1 1 1 )", "( 1 1 0 ) ( 1 1 1 )", "( 0 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )", 
    "( 2 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )", "( 1 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 )")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
> dput(ARIMA_Order2)
structure(c(2L, 54L, 93L), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("( 2 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )", "( 2 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 )", "( 0 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )"
    )), .Names = ""), class = "table")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dd1 <- as.data.table(t1)
dd2 <- as.data.table(t2)
merge(dd1, dd2, by="Var1", incomparables=NA, all=TRUE)
```

Is it OK ?

```
> merge(dd1,dd2, by="Var1", incomparables = NA, all=TRUE)
                 Var1 Freq.x Freq.y
1 ( 2 1 1 ) ( 1 1 1 )      1     NA
2 ( 1 1 0 ) ( 1 1 1 )      3     NA
3 ( 0 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )     29     93
4 ( 2 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )     54      2
5 ( 1 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 )     58     NA
6 ( 2 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 )     NA     54
```

To have the frequencies in rows:

```
> ddd <- merge(dd1, dd2, ...) # as above
> ddd <- dd[,-1]
> rownames(ddd) <- dd$Var1
> t(ddd)
       ( 2 1 1 ) ( 1 1 1 ) ( 1 1 0 ) ( 1 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 )
Freq.x                   1                   3                  29
Freq.y                  NA                  NA                  93
       ( 2 1 1 ) ( 0 1 1 ) ( 1 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 ) ( 2 1 0 ) ( 0 1 1 )
Freq.x                  54                  58                  NA
Freq.y                   2                  NA                  54
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Its importing to me, to have the different types of models as columns and the frequencies in rows

Comment: Thanks that helps ! Is it possible to merge lets say 10 instead of 2 results with the merge function ?

Comment: @Vala Hmmm... no. `merge` is for two dataframes only. This is another interesting problem.

Comment: @Vala "merge several data frames" on Google gives some results.